# Vertical line in 3rd order derivative of 1/x^2

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have drawn the graphs of derivatives of $$\frac{1}{x^2}$$ up to 5th order. I have understood all the graphs. But the thing i'm wonder at is the vertical line at x=0. This line appears after 2nd order derivative. So how this line came?

[See graphs here at Desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bw4k5uwy7b)

[See image of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SU4q.png)

Comment: That vertical line is a vertical asymptote. The function isn't even defined at $\;x=0\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio If it's asymptote then why it came after 2nd order derivative?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by "it came **after** second derivative..."

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean desmos doesn't draw line $$x=0$$ in first & second derivative. But after 2nd derivative it draw that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line you're seeing on the desmos graphs I think is just a problem with desmos. The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuously differentiable everywhere but $x=0$. If you take the derivatives by hand and don't just plug in $f'''(x)$ into desmos then you don't get that line